# Improving the Performance of SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a SQL Query that involves `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `UNION` and `SUBQUERY` which is taking a long time to execute. My SQL skills are not that great and I would appreciate if someone can help me how can I optimize the following query to make it faster.

```
SELECT [l].[ACCOUNT_ID]
      ,[l].[CONTACT_ID]
      ,[l].[JOB_ROLE]
      ,[l].[JOB_FUNCTION]
      ,[l].[STATE]
      ,[l].[COUNTRY]
      ,[acc].[EMPLOYEE_COUNT] AS [EmpSize]
      ,[r].[CALL_DATE]
      , CONVERT(varchar(20), [r].[DURATION]) AS [COMMENTS]
      ,[r].[LOCATIONS]
FROM [dbo].[tbl_V_S_CONTACT] AS [l]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[CALL_DETAILS_RECORDS_CLEAN] AS [r] ON [l].[CONTACT_ID] = [r].[CON_PER_ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_V_S_ACCOUNT] AS [acc] ON [l].[ACCOUNT_ID] = [acc].[ACCT_ID]
WHERE [l].[CONTACT_ID] IN (SELECT [b].[CON_PER_ID]
                           FROM [dbo].[S_SRC] AS [a]
                           INNER JOIN [dbo].[S_CAMP_CON] AS [b] ON [a].[ROW_ID] = [b].[SRC_ID] 
                           WHERE [a].[STATUS_CD] = 'Launched'
                           AND [a].[PROG_END_DT] > CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 101))
AND [l].[COUNTRY] IN ('United States', 'Canada')
AND [r].[CALL_DATE] >= '01-01-2017' AND [r].[CALL_DATE] <= '2018-03-20'
UNION
SELECT [l].[ACCOUNT_ID]
      ,[l].[CONTACT_ID]
      ,[l].[JOB_ROLE]
      ,[l].[JOB_FUNCTION]
      ,[l].[STATE]
      ,[l].[COUNTRY]
      ,[acc].[EMPLOYEE_COUNT] AS [EmpSize]
      ,[act].[TODO_PLAN_START_DT] AS [CALL_DATE]
      ,[act].[COMMENTS]
      ,'Philadelphia' AS [LOCATIONS]
FROM [dbo.tbl_V_S_CONTACT] AS [l]
INNER JOIN [SiebProd].[dbo].[S_EVT_ACT] AS [act] ON [l].[CONTACT_ID] = [act].[PR_CON_ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_V_S_ACCOUNT] AS [acc] ON [l].[ACCOUNT_ID] = [acc].[ACCT_ID]
WHERE [l].[CONTACT_ID] IN (SELECT [b].[CON_PER_ID]
                           FROM [dbo].[S_SRC] AS [a]
                           INNER JOIN [dbo].[S_CAMP_CON] AS [b] ON [a].[ROW_ID] = [b].[SRC_ID]
                           WHERE [a].[STATUS_CD] = 'Launched'
                           AND [a].[PROG_END_DT] > CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 101))
AND [l].[COUNTRY] IN ('United States', 'Canada')
AND [act].[CEM_PLAN_START_DT] <= CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 101)
AND [act].[TODO_CD] = 'Call Disposition'
AND [act].[COMMENTS] IS NOT NULL
AND [act.REF_NUM] IS NOT NULL
AND [X_CALL_DISPOSITION] IS NOT NULL
AND [act].[X_DISPOSITION_FLG] = 'Y'
```

Comment: it would be very helpful to see the T-SQL `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables involved, and post the execution plan to https://pastetheplan.com

Comment: pastetheplan.com is not working. Can I Edit the question and paste it here?

Comment: ok, try this:  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Thanks for the link but sorry I'm not able to post the schema of all the tables involved. If you can give bullet point recommendations on how to write a query, even that will be helpful

Comment: Your query contains a union.  Have you tried running each part of the union separately to see which one is the bottleneck?  The process of unioning could be a potential bottleneck as well.  One way to find out!

Comment: It's hard to reproduce your situation. I'm seeing your `date` filter might be the culprit. Try to convert the columns to `DATE` instead of converting the `GETDATE()` to `varchar`

Comment: *I'm not able to post the schema of all the tables involved* Then your post is too broad for this site. *If you can give bullet points* Not how this site works.

Comment: Ok, so I tried `SELECT TOP 1000` for the first part of `UNION` and it didn't produce any row and it has been more than 4 mins now. Could it be the `subquery`?

Comment: Converting `GETDATE()` to `DATE` instead of `VARCHAR` is also not doing any good.

Comment: Found the bottleneck. The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with `[dbo].[tbl_V_S_ACCOUNT]` is the issue. I ran the query by commenting  `LEFT OUTER JOIN` out and the query performs a lot faster. Will it help if I provide the schema for `[dbo].[tbl_V_S_ACCOUNT]`?

Comment: Performance wise, there is a very big difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL`. You need to work out whether `UNION ALL` will give you correct results. `EXISTS` may perform better than `IN (SELECT...)` in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many steps to improve your query.

First correct one issue,

My code is untested but it will definitely improve performance.
understand the idea and fix error if any

```
-- Put all require columns of [dbo].[tbl_V_S_CONTACT] AS [l]
Create table #Contact(ACCOUNT_ID,CONTACT_ID,JOB_ROLE,JOB_FUNCTION,STATE,COUNTRY)

INSERT INTO #Contact
SELECT [l].[ACCOUNT_ID]
      ,[l].[CONTACT_ID]
      ,[l].[JOB_ROLE]
      ,[l].[JOB_FUNCTION]
      ,[l].[STATE]
      ,[l].[COUNTRY]
      ,[acc].[EMPLOYEE_COUNT] AS [EmpSize]        
FROM [dbo].[tbl_V_S_CONTACT] AS [l]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_V_S_ACCOUNT] AS [acc] ON [l].[ACCOUNT_ID] = [acc].[ACCT_ID]
WHERE [l].[CONTACT_ID] IN (SELECT [b].[CON_PER_ID]
                           FROM [dbo].[S_SRC] AS [a]
                           INNER JOIN [dbo].[S_CAMP_CON] AS [b] ON [a].[ROW_ID] = [b].[SRC_ID] 
                           WHERE [a].[STATUS_CD] = 'Launched'
                           AND [a].[PROG_END_DT] > CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 101))
AND [l].[COUNTRY] IN ('United States', 'Canada')




SELECT [l].[ACCOUNT_ID]
      ,[l].[CONTACT_ID]
      ,[l].[JOB_ROLE]
      ,[l].[JOB_FUNCTION]
      ,[l].[STATE]
      ,[l].[COUNTRY]
      ,[acc].[EMPLOYEE_COUNT] AS [EmpSize]
      ,[r].[CALL_DATE]
      , CONVERT(varchar(20), [r].[DURATION]) AS [COMMENTS]
      ,[r].[LOCATIONS]
FROM #Contact AS [l]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[CALL_DETAILS_RECORDS_CLEAN] AS [r] ON [l].[CONTACT_ID] = [r].[CON_PER_ID]

WHERE [r].[CALL_DATE] >= '01-01-2017' AND [r].[CALL_DATE] <= '2018-03-20'

UNION -- use UNION ALL if possible

SELECT [l].[ACCOUNT_ID]
      ,[l].[CONTACT_ID]
      ,[l].[JOB_ROLE]
      ,[l].[JOB_FUNCTION]
      ,[l].[STATE]
      ,[l].[COUNTRY]
      ,[acc].[EMPLOYEE_COUNT] AS [EmpSize]
      ,[act].[TODO_PLAN_START_DT] AS [CALL_DATE]
      ,[act].[COMMENTS]
      ,'Philadelphia' AS [LOCATIONS]
FROM #Contact AS [l]
INNER JOIN [SiebProd].[dbo].[S_EVT_ACT] AS [act] ON [l].[CONTACT_ID] = [act].[PR_CON_ID]

WHERE [act].[CEM_PLAN_START_DT] <= CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 101)
AND [act].[TODO_CD] = 'Call Disposition'
AND [act].[COMMENTS] IS NOT NULL
AND [act.REF_NUM] IS NOT NULL
AND [X_CALL_DISPOSITION] IS NOT NULL
AND [act].[X_DISPOSITION_FLG] = 'Y'
```

Comment: Yes I forgot to use Exists, I will correct it if there is any improvement

Comment: This has improved the performance pretty well. Thanks a lot, everyone for your suggestions. I'm accepting this answer.